# Windows FTP Server with XCRC and SSL (Other than CuteFTP SS)

Tags: ssl, ftp

I am currently using CuteFTP Secure Sever 3.3 but it has problems.  It seems to muck up connection management, drop connections occasionally and die on large files.

I am looking for a replacement that supports XCRC because I use the *Synchronize Folders* function in the CuteFTP client.  I would prefer to detect file similarity by XCRC rather than a simple size/name/modification date if possible.

Are there any other servers that support XCRC and SSL? I am looking for recommendations, not a regular list scraped from Google.  I am hoping to save my self the time of trying each one out individually.

Answer (score 2):

[SmartFTP](http://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/2549) supports XCRC, and works quite well. It isn't open source or free, but it is a decent product. The linked page also shows some FTP Servers that support it as well.

Answer (score 1):

FileZilla is always good if that's truly what you want.  http://filezilla-project.org/

SmartFTP also has a list of FTP servers supporting XCRC http://www.smartftp.com/support/kb/2549

Comment: FileZilla doesn't support XCRC

Comment: @Dr.Zim no thats not good.  Because using that logic the web would not progress at the pace it is today, for example vendor browsers implement features well in advanced of the W3C, which are (much) later formalised via the W3C.  By implemented features not part of standards you progress everyone forward quicker.  If the feature is no good it just later gets dropped.  XCRC would be a really useful feature NOW.

Answer (score 1):

[Serv-U](http://www.serv-u.com/) ftp server, not free but is quite good